# The process about one Object Defined by Anonymous Object?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout<<"Base()"<<endl;
    }

    Base(const Base& b) 
    {
        cout<<"Base(Base&)"<<endl;
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        cout<<"~Base()"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base b = Base();
    return 0;
}
```

platform: win7/ CodeBlock/ mingw
output result on my screen:

> Base()
>      ~Base()

why Base(Base&) was not called?

My Question:
In `main()`, `Base b = Base();` , I think `Base()` will call `Base()` Constructor and then a anonymous object was built,  after that, "Base b = anonymous object" will call `Base(const Base& b)`, but the output result tell me that the copy-constructor was not called. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I may be wrong but object initialization is different from object construction. Also, there's no operator=(const Base&) defined. :).

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan Well, there's no assignment anywhere, so...